# Funcionalidade: indicação de usuarios

Tags: debate, novo-recurso

Ao usar o site, sempre notamos usuários com mais domínio em certos assuntos, existem perguntas que penso "Poxa, fulano responderia facilmente isso aqui!".

Sei que existem as tags favoritas, mas para um engajamento maior, não seria interessante a possibilidade de indicar usuários nas perguntas?

Comment: Hoje existe o fragmento _"Conhece alguém que pode responder? Compartilhe um link para esta pergunta por e-mail, no Google+, Twitter ou Facebook."_ em perguntas sem nenhuma resposta. Pode compartilhar a pergunta marcando a pessoa no chat, que será notificada. (Btw, o downvote não foi meu)

Comment: Eu sou um dos que usa o chat para ver se alguém consegue resolver meu problema... com moderação, claro

Comment: Olá Felipe, somos colaboradores aqui, respondemos quando podemos, é comunitário, fazer isso é interessante, quando você tem alguma "amizade", mas o foco aqui é ser comunitário, atua quem quer e quem pode, não ganhamos nada para atuar aqui, espero que entenda o espirito do site ;)

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento, já entendi, estava me referindo a algo interno, como o encaminhar do whatsapp ou o marcar do facebook, mas realmente isso não se enquadraria aqui.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Você gosta de SPAM?

Gosta de ser incomodado quando está ocupado?

E pessoas inconvenientes e repetitivas?

Se fosse possível indicar algum usuário nas perguntas seria mais ou menos isso que aconteceria.

Deve-se lembrar que responder perguntas é algo que fazemos **quando** queremos e **porque** queremos, pois não recebemos pra isso. A pessoa "obrigada" a responder é um consultor pago pra isso. Só que esse não é o foco de nenhum dos sites da rede.

Comment: Tirando a Ignorância, +1 pra ti, mas bom, é claro que se existisse essa funcionalidade seria possível configura-la, também não enxergo o SOpt com um nível de imaturidade tão grande assim.

Comment: @FelipeDuarte Não quis ser ignorante. Mas realmente não pensei em como as palavras iam soar... Me desculpe.

Comment: Eu particularmente entendi o tom de voz como uma metáfora do porquê a ideia não é adequada...

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado a intenção foi fazer o leitor pensar em como poderia ser prejudicial pra *ele mesmo* se isso fosse implementado. Mas não posso dizer que tenha pensado no tom de voz...

Comment: Não vi ignorância nenhuma, só a mais pura verdade escrita de forma direta e sem enrolação, e concordo totalmente com ela. +1

Comment: @Articuno, sei que a intenção do EMBarbosa não foi essa, mas o problema é como se lê, essa construção de frase interrogativa (pelo menos aqui no Brasil) lembra algo apelativo, poderia usar facilmente esse tipo de expressão para ilustrar uma mãe dando bronca em seu filho, ou o mesmo entre chefe e funcionário, a resposta é boa, e também concordo, mas é inegável teor de ignorância.